# Why is it saying that found.remove() is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const names = ['Milan', 'Poudel', 'Soudel', 'Academia']
found = names.filter(function(name) {
  return name.includes('ou')
})

found.remove()
console.log(names)
```

Comment: what will `remove` do? And what is your expectation?

Comment: JavaScript arrays don't have a `remove()` method.

Comment: Unless you had created that method yourself, there is no `Array.prototype.remove` anywhere. Have a look at the list here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Instance_methods

Comment: Even if there were a `remove()` method, how would you expect calling it on `found` would change `names`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause `.remove` is not really an Array function.
You can use just `filter`

```js
const names = ['Milan', 'Poudel', 'Soudel', 'Academia']
const filteredNames = names.filter((name) => !name.includes('ou'))

console.log(filteredNames)
```

Comment: He already knows how to use `filter()`, it's in the function.

Comment: I am actually trying to remove all those which contains ''ou" from the array

Comment: @MilanPoudel Isn't that what this does? You just have to invert the test.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all elements with 'ou' do this.

```
let names = ['Milan', 'Poudel', 'Soudel', 'Academia']    
names = names.filter(function(name) {
  return !(name.includes('ou'));
})
console.log(names);
```

Comment: wont work cause you can't reassign `const`, use `let` instead

Comment: OR you can go the way @onecompileman did ! If you do not want to mess with existing array.

Answer (score 0):

Where is `.remove()` coming from exactly? Are you using an library of some sort? That's is imperative to providing an accurate answer.

To explain your process, and where it's flawed, here is a walkthrough:

```js
// Array of strings is initialized
const names = ['Milan', 'Poudel', 'Soudel', 'Academia']

/**
* Filter the names array and return 
* a new array of strings that INCLUDE
* strings with 'ou' which will
* be stored in a global variable 'found'
*/
found = names.filter(function(name) {
  return name.includes('ou')
})

// Result ['Poudel', 'Soudel']
console.log(found);


// Exception thrown because Array.remove is not a function
found.remove()

/**
* names is still in-tact and in it's original
* state since you returned the result of
* your names.filter function into a global
* variable called 'found'
*/
console.log(names)
```

Are you trying to create an `Array.remove` function? Maybe that could look something like this:

```js
Array.prototype.remove = function (name) {
  return this.filter( e => !e.includes(name));
}

let names = ['Milan', 'Poudel', 'Soudel', 'Academia']

names = names.remove('ou')
console.log(names)
```